Why does build fail after attempting to create a development build after installing sentry for expo app?
⚠️  ld: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++'

› Generating debug somaticsFrontend » somaticsFrontend.app.dSYM
› Executing somaticsFrontend » Bundle React Native code and images
Bundler cache is empty, rebuilding (this may take a minute)
❌  error: Auth token is required for this request. Please run sentry-cli login and try again!
⚠️  Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
To fix, go to: Xcode » somaticsFrontend/somaticsFrontend » Build Phases » 'Upload Debug Symbols to Sentry'
Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/somaticsFrontend-dgdupxvzovrlqbajsudymjphqwdc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/somaticsFrontend/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/somaticsFrontend.build/Release-iphoneos/somaticsFrontend.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'somaticsFrontend' from project 'somaticsFrontend')
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/somaticsFrontend-dgdupxvzovrlqbajsudymjphqwdc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/somaticsFrontend/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/somaticsFrontend.build/Release-iphoneos/somaticsFrontend.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'somaticsFrontend' from project 'somaticsFrontend')
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
